# Create rest service Umbraco 7 backOffice

Tags: asp.net-web-api, umbraco, umbraco7

I read a lot on this issue. 
I read that I can use at web api asp.net to create rest service in Umbraco.

Can I create this api in Umbraco back office?
If not, how do I connect the service to my local Umbraco site?

I can't find a simple tutorial that shows this.

EDIT:

I want to get Umbraco content data in client side.I read that I can create in server side(Umbraco) rest service that I can get data when I call to specific url to my Umbraco server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at https://our.umbraco.org/DOCUMENTATION/Reference/WebApi/ - the article explains how to create controllers inheriting from UmbracoApiController.

**EDIT - I added this example:**

I made a controller like this:

```
public class PartnersController : UmbracoApiController
{ 
    public IEnumerable GetPartners(string zip = "") { ... } 
}
```

Then I used jQuery and AngularJS like this:

```
function getPartnersForZip($scope, $http) {
    $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/umbraco/api/partners/getpartners/?zip=' + getQueryVariable("zip") }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.partners = data;
    });
}

<div ng-controller="getPartnersForZip" ng-cloak>
    <ul class="dealer-list" ng-cloak>
        <li ng-repeat="partner in partners"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This works for me. What have you tried?

Comment: I read this article. It's doesn't clear. When i call in url to api/controller it's dosen't work.(404 http error)

Comment: I added an example that might help.

Comment: when i add my controller.cs. according to article you need to put this file in ~Umbraco/Api/[YourControllerName] , but i get 404 custom - "No umbraco document matches the url '/Api/TestController'."

Comment: No, you don't put it in an /umbraco/api/ folder - put it in App_Code instead. /umbraco/api/ is just the route that Umbraco uses. When you create a class using UmbracoApiController, Umbraco registers that and crestes the route for you. Also, the controller class name has to end with Controller.

Comment: Didn't there used to be a built in API for accessing Documents from Umbraco? i.e if you had a News document type you could just call www.mysite.com/api/news/12 to get the news item with ID 12?

Comment: @DanHarris Not to my knowledge.

Comment: Do not include the "controller" part of the file name.  So if your controller is named TestController, path should be "Umbraco/Api/Test/MethodName